# Pinging with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working through this book https://www.amazon.co.uk/Mastering-Python-Networking-Security-networking/dp/1788992512/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=mastering+python+networking&qid=1567971919&s=gateway&sr=8-4  And I'm struggling with this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys, argparse, pdb

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Ping Scan Network')
parser.add_argument('-network', dest='network',
            help='NetWork segment [For example 192.168.55]', required=False)
parser.add_argument('-machines', dest='machines', help='Machines number',
                    type=int, required=True)
parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
for ip in range(1, parsed_args.machines +1):
    ip_add = parsed_args.network +'.'+ str(ip)
    print(f'Scanning {ip_add}')
    if sys.platform == 'linux':
        #pdb.set_trace()
        subprocess = Popen(['/bin/ping', '-c 1 ', ip_add], stdin=PIPE,
                        stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    elif sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        subprocess = Popen(['ping', ip_add], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
                        stderr=PIPE)


stdout, stderr = subprocess.communicate(input=None)
stdout = stdout.decode('utf-8')
print(stdout)
if 'Lost = 0' in stdout or 'bytes from ' in stdout:
    print(f'The ip address {stdout} has responded with a ECHO_REPLY !')
```

I used the python debugger to find out what's in variables in every line and it seems that the line `stdout, stderr = subprocess.communicate(input=None)` assigns nothing to `stdout` hence nothing is being printed out.

The purpose of this script is to send dummy packets to defined target ip and see if you get response. However, I'm getting absolutely nothing. I tried ip address of my laptop as well as tablet. All I'm getting is output from the `print` statement in `print(f'Scanning {ip_add}')` but nothing further down.

What am I missing here ?

**Update:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys, argparse, pdb

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Ping Scan Network')
parser.add_argument('-network', dest='network',
            help='NetWork segment [For example 192.168.55]', required=False)
parser.add_argument('-machines', dest='machines', help='Machines number',
                    type=int, required=True)
parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
process = []
for ip in range(1, parsed_args.machines +1):
    ip_add = parsed_args.network +'.'+ str(ip)
    print(f'Scanning {ip_add}')
    if sys.platform == 'linux':
        #pdb.set_trace()
        process = Popen(['/bin/ping', '-c 1 ', ip_add], stdin=PIPE,
                        stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    elif sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        process = Popen(['ping', ip_add], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
                        stderr=PIPE)


stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input=None)
stdout = stdout.decode('utf-8')
print(stdout)
if 'Lost = 0' in stdout or 'bytes from ' in stdout:
    print(f'The ip address {stdout} has responded with a ECHO_REPLY !')
```

Comment: I've just tried to run the script and it worked without any issues, albeit on macos. The few things to note: 1) the script would only try to communicate with the latest machine as the `subprocess.communicate()` is called outside of the loop; 2) I'd recommend to rename subprocess variable to not shadow the package name; 3) could you show how exactly are you calling the script and what is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: `subprocess` is defined in your for loop scope. Create `subprocess` before the loop to have access after the loop. The code seems to run fine with just adding `subprocess = []` before the loop. Also, beware of the shadow issue here per the comment above.

Comment: I'm executing the script by running `./script.py -network 192.168.1.7 -machines 1` but still getting nothing except from that one line from `print`.

Comment: Does it matter which program is used or is `ping` essential for the problem? Also, don't add multiple "edit" sections, your question should be a single, well-formed text.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  Well, I'm learning how to ping remote machine using Python so having it not working is a problem at this point.

Comment: Sorry, but then your question is off-topic. You first need to extract a [mcve]. This example doesn't have to solve your initial task, in only has to demonstrate the problem you're having, and *nothing* else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script is looping through machines on the network. Assuming a class c like my local - is 10.0.0 and you have up to 256 machines on there.

So to run I'm entering `./scriptName.py -network 10.0.0 -machines 255`

Also, declaring subprocess before the loop and commenting out some of your prints and moving the bottom lines into the loop it is successful for my local network. Of course it takes a long time waiting for the timeouts.

```py
#!/home/dave/.virtualenvs/chat1/bin/python3
import argparse
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Ping Scan Network')
parser.add_argument('-network', dest='network',
                    help='NetWork segment [For example 192.168.55]', required=False)
parser.add_argument('-machines', dest='machines', help='Machines number',
                    type=int, required=True)
parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
print(f'parsed args {parsed_args}')
subprocess = []
for ip in range(1, parsed_args.machines + 1):
    ip_add = parsed_args.network + '.' + str(ip)
    # print(f'Scanning {ip_add}')
    if sys.platform == 'linux':
        # pdb.set_trace()
        subprocess = Popen(['/bin/ping', '-c 1 ', ip_add], stdin=PIPE,
                           stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    elif sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        subprocess = Popen(['ping', ip_add], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
                           stderr=PIPE)

    stdout, stderr = subprocess.communicate(input=None)
    stdout = stdout.decode('utf-8')
    # print(stdout)
    if 'Lost = 0' in stdout or 'bytes from ' in stdout:
        print(f'{sys.platform} with ip address {stdout} has responded with a ECHO_REPLY !')
```

Outputs Example:

```
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.035/0.035/0.035/0.000 ms
 has responded with a ECHO_REPLY !
linux with ip address PING 10.0.0.156 (10.0.0.156) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.156: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.800 ms

--- 10.0.0.156 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.800/0.800/0.800/0.000 ms
 has responded with a ECHO_REPLY !
```

Comment: Moving the unindented code into for loop helped. Didn't occur to me it should be included in the loop. Plus `./scriptName.py -network 10.0.0 -machines 255` did the trick too. Just out of curiosity what the 10.0.0 means ? Is it another way of defining localhost as if 127.0.0.1 ? I get expected output now.

Comment: `10.0.0` is another option for a local/private network just like `192.168.nnn` - just my router's setup.